# 2D arrays and double pointers in C

Tags: c, pointers, multidimensional-array

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [2D arrays and pointers.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6114072/2d-arrays-and-pointers)
>   *(This is not a duplicate of that question.  In that question the OP was correctly passing a pointer-to-a-pointer, and the problem was with dereferencing an uninitialised pointer.  This question is about passing trying to pass a pointer-to-array to a function that expects a pointer-to-a-pointer.)*

For compatibility with some existing code, I need to pass a 2D array to a function as a pointer-to-a-pointer. I have simplified the code below. After it prints the first value in the structure and `newptr` in the function `printvalues`, i.e. "My value is 123 and in struct 123", I get a seg. fault. What am I missing?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct mystruct
{
   char  mychar [4][5];
} mystruct_t;

void printvalues( char** newptr )
{
  int i;
  mystruct_t * fd = (mystruct_t*)malloc(sizeof(*fd));
  for ( i = 0; i < 3; i++ )
  {
    strcpy(fd->mychar[i], newptr[i]);
    printf( "My value is %s and in struct %s\n", newptr[i], fd->mychar[i] );
  }
}

int main( int argc, char **argv )
{
   int i;
   char *ptr = malloc(4*sizeof(char));
   char **pptr = (char **) malloc(5*sizeof(char *));  

   char  abc[4][5] = { "123", "456", "789" };

   for ( i = 0; i < 3; i++ )
   {
      printf( "My value is %s\n", abc[i] );
   }

   ptr = abc;
   printvalues(&ptr );
}
```

Comment: @lostinpointers: Please don't simply repost the same problem. If you feel that this is a different problem you should (1) acknowledge the earlier question, (2) tell what you have done since then, and (3) be specific about how this question is new.

Comment: The line: `ptr = abc;` (third from bottom to top) gives me an error:
`warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type`.

Comment: It is worth pointing out that while you can access data stored in a `char**` with the `foo[][]`, syntax it is *not the same thing* as a `char[][]`.

Comment: Did not notice the duplicate, going to delete my answer.

Comment: This is not actually a duplicate of that question at all!

Comment: Reflecting on @caf's analysis I've thrown my weight into the re-open effort, but I would like to see some sign that @lostinpointers is making an effort here.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a two dimensional array (like you do with abc) and you only dereference one of the dimensions, you cannot honestly expect it to resolve to a character.  It would resolve to the address of the row of characters.

```
char  abc[4][5] = { "123", "456", "789" };

for ( i = 0; i < 3; i++ )
{
   printf( "My value is %s\n", abc[i] );
}
```

makes no sense.  you need something more like:

```
char  abc[4][5] = { "123", "456", "789" };

for ( i = 0; i < 3; i++ )
{
   for (j = 0; j < 4; j++ )
   {
     printf( "My value is %c\n", abc[i][j] );
   }
}
```